# OAuth Provider in Drupal 6

Tags: 6, users, services, authentication-authorization

I am absolutely stumbling in configuring OAuth as a service provider in d6 which is mainly used via login. I have worked extensively with Services in D7, but services is not even there in D6.

How should I go about something like this?

Comment: Services for D6 has been revoked because it doesn't have a maintainer while security issues were found.
If you're not prepared to use D7 you will need to do quite a bit of custom work yourself.

Comment: @BojanZivanovic - Thanks mate. Can you briefly tell me if you wanted to have SSO with a website built on D6, how would you go about this?

Comment: Look into OpenID: https://drupal.org/project/openid_provider